# MapBox: assign an icon to the points

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm trying to assign an icon to the points from a GeoJSON. I use this snippet:

```
    map.addSource('Punti di allerta', {
        type: 'geojson',
        data: source_attentionpoints, 
    });
    map.addLayer({
        'id': 'Punti di allerta',
        'type': 'circle',
        'source': 'Punti di allerta',
        'layout': {
            'icon-image': '{% static 'image/webgis/icons/warning50.png' %}',
            'icon-size': 0.5
        }
    });
```

I see this two errors and the points are not rendered:

> Error: "layers.Punti di allerta.layout.icon-image: unknown property
>   "icon-image"" Error: "layers.Punti di allerta.layout.icon-size:
>   unknown property "icon-size""

But if I use this snippet instead of the previous I can see all points without problems:

```
map.addLayer({
    'id': 'Punti di allerta',
    'type': 'circle',
    'source': 'Punti di allerta',
     'paint': {
         'circle-radius': 8,
         'circle-color': 'rgb(0,0,0)',
         'circle-opacity': 1.0,
         'circle-stroke-width': 4,
         'circle-stroke-color': 'rgb(200,200,200)',
         'circle-stroke-opacity': 1.0,
         'circle-blur': 0,
    }
});
```

What I've wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found the problem. There are two errors inside my code:

1. `'type': 'circle'` instead of `'type': 'symbol'`
2. I need this before add.Layer:

   ```
   map.loadImage(
       '{% static 'image/webgis/icons/warning50.png' %}',
       function(error, image) {
           if (error) throw error;
           map.addImage('warning', image);
           }
   );
   ```